# Regular expression to return all match occurrences

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I have text like below-

`02052020 02:40:02.445: Vacation Allowance: 21; nnnnnn Vacation Allowance: 22;nnn`

I want to extract the below in Python-

```
Vacation Allowance: 21
Vacation Allowance: 22
```

Basically, I want to extract all occurrences of "Vacation Allowance:" and the numerical value following this suffixed with ;

I'm using the below regular expression-

```
(.*)(Vacation Allowance:)(.*);(.*)
```

Full Python code below-

```
import re

text = '02/05/2020 Vacation Allowance: 21; 02/05/2020 Vacation Allowance: 22; nnn'

pattern = re.compile(r'(.*)(Vacation Allowance:)(.*);(.*)')

for (a,b,c,d) in re.findall(pattern, text):
    print(b, " ", c)
```

This does not all give all occurrences, but gives only the last occurrence. The current output is-

```
Vacation Allowance: 22
```

Can you please comment on how I can extract all occurrences?

Comment: Just use `\bVacation Allowance:\s*\d+;`

Comment: in what language you want to implement this?

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Comment: I need this in Python.

Comment: @anubhava- Thanks for your comment. I tried your suggestion, but it doesn't work. BTW, I'm trying this in Python. I have now clarified this in the original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the regular expression used.
The `(.*)` blocks are accepting more of the string than you realize - `.*` is referred to as a greedy operation and it will consume as much of the string as it can while still matching. This is why you only see one output.

Suggest matching something like `Vacation Allowance:\s*\d+;` or similar.

```
text = '02/05/2020 Vacation Allowance: 21; 02/05/2020 Vacation Allowance: 22; nnn'
m = re.findall('Vacation Allowance:\s*(\d*);', text, re.M)
print(m)
```

result: `['21', '22']`

Comment: Thanks Petriborg for clarifying on (.*) being a greedy operation. I have moved to using string functions (instead of regexp) because there were other patterns to match as well and the value is not always numerical. I'm marking this as the correct answer, as it highlights the issue correctly and lead me to look for an alternate solution.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript it would be `'text'.match(/\bVacation Allowance: \d+/g)`

You need the global attribute `g`

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is how I used your suggestion in Python and it doesn't work. There is no result.

import re

text = '02/05/2020 0Vacation Allowance: 21; 02/05/2020 Vacation Allowance: 22; nnn'
pattern = re.compile(r'\bVacation Allowance: \d+/g')
print(re.findall(pattern, text))

Comment: Oh, Python. it's `pattern = re.compile(r'\bVacation Allowance: \d+')`, no `/g` in Python as you can do findall.

Comment: Thanks Thanos. I have moved to using string functions (instead of regexp) because there were other patterns to match as well and the value is not always numerical. With regexp, I'm forced to use .*, which as clarified by @Petriborg is a greedy operation and is causing issues.